# Is this part of code in Jenkinsfile shell script syntax or Groovy syntax?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I am new to Jenkinsfile.

I am seeing below code in Jenkinsfile and I am having syntax understanding problem with the export statement below.

```
export creds=\$(aws ecr get-authorization-token --region ap-southeast-2 --output text --query authorizationData[].authorizationToken | base64 -d | cut -d: -f2)
docker login -u AWS -p \$creds $GlobalVars.dockerECR
```

If I tried to run the export statement in its simplified version like:

```
 export creds=\$(date)
```

in shell, it would give error:

> -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('.

So it's not shell script syntax? but it does not look like Groovy syntax either.

### Edit

If \ is needed to escape $ in Groovy, then why in second line,

```
docker login -u AWS -p \$creds $GlobalVars.dockerECR
```

$GlobalVars is not escaped?

Comment: `$` is used in both Groovy and bash for string interpolation, and Groovy is the first to process it. To pass it to bash, you need to escape it as `\$`.

Comment: It is a shell syntax wrapped inside a Groovy method argument.

Comment: @MaratC thanks, but if that's the case, why in 2nd line, $GlobalVars, it's not escaped with \

Comment: I didn't write that code so I have no idea. It could be that `GlobalVars` is a Groovy variable (map) that has `dockerECR` key, or it could be that it evaluates to an empty string and that's OK. You should address that question to whoever wrote that code.